# I am simulating an equivalent model of a laser in LTspice shown below. I am supposed to plot the power at node Pout versus the input current

Tags: resistors, ltspice, simulation, load, optoelectronics

The issue is I am not able to plot the power without adding the load resistor which is not specified in the equivalent circuit.

[image]

Is there any other way to plot the power? If not, then what value of load resistor should I take?

Comment: I'll give you a tip, you don't need to use PWR(x,y) to get powers of 10. You can use scientific notation, so instead of 20*PWR(10,23) you can just use 20E23. Also holding ALT and clicking a component will plot the power dissipated in that component, so that might be useful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\$ v(pout) = v(vph) \times 0.002593 \$. Why all the extra circuitry (B1 is extraneous, E1 is extraneous but makes it clear that a scaling factor is involved)? v(pout) is a voltage with infinite resistance connected to the node, thus zero power.

Not understanding the intent of your model, I have a suspicion that the power is the voltage at node *pout* which is node *vph* scaled by E1. If you want the graph to read in watts, multiply v(pout) by *1A*, i.e., \$ V(pout)*1A \$. This will make the y-axis read out in watts as shown in the example below.

[image]

Comment: You are correct the power at the node pout is actually the scaled node voltage vph.

Comment: but I am not getting the desired graph. The plot should look like an L-I curve of a laser rather it is coming out to be a straight line starting from the origin. which is close enough but it should not start from the origin, it should start from some point on the x-axis.

Comment: @L1234  Sounds to me like your specific question of "How do I plot the power?" was answered and now you're discussing something unrelated which is "the power plot is wrong".  Probably best to accept this answer and start a new question explaining the plot you're getting and why you believe it to be wrong and why it should look differently.  You have some pretty complicated equations in your behavioral components.  It might be a good idea to take the suggestion under your question and use scientific notation to rewrite the expressions so they're easier to comprehend.

Comment: @L1234 An odd thought, have you tried an alternate integration method? *Modified Trap* was changed about 6 years ago which caused strange behaviour for some circuits. Try changing the integration method to *Gear* by adding *.options method=gear* to your simulation.